# How to log a request in stdout Node

Tags: node.js, logging, request

I need to log every API request to stdout (datetime, method, url, ip). I would like to enable this feature according to a configuration option. but I don't know how to do it. I'm jus using Node and esLint. Someone can help me ?

Comment: `console.log(stuff_i_want_to_log)`?

Comment: No friend, is not that simple, how can I log Date,IP, etc.... and make it visible by a configuration option ?

Comment: You have provided almost zero details on what you're using so the answer to that is "it depends". This question is both too thin on specifics and way too broad in scope, it's really off-topic here unless you can narrow it down and explain more about what you're trying to do, *especially in terms of actual code*.